# How to detect clicks on an element inside an ion-item?

Tags: ionic-framework

Using ion-list and ion-item, I am unable to detect a tap on an element such as a button or a div.

For exemple, using ng-click doesn't work here:

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="device in devices">
          <div ng-click="deviceOption(device.id)"> CLICK HERE</div>                                            
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I have tried using ion-option-button instead but it is not straigthforward to use.

Why can't we have a simple *ion-button* directive for detecting clicks inside ion-item ?

Comment: Do you mean `ng-click` doesn't work here?

Comment: Indeed, ng-click doesn't work here

Comment: add a codepen please

Comment: Have you tried putting the ngClick directly on the ion-item instead of the child div?

Comment: That's the thing: I don't want to react to a click on the whole item (this works fine by the way); I want to be able to trigger different callbacks depending on which item's element the user has clicked on

Comment: Yeah, it would be best if you could replicate this in a codepen. I have some similar setups that are working just fine.

Comment: @matdev, if you expect a quick reply and accurate one, please consider again adding a codepen. You are the person requesting help and others time and you shall gives us as maximum into and tools to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the issue has to do with the `ion-item` changing the `z-index` of the inner `div` and the click cannot propagate through. You can get around it easily, change the `z-index` of the inner `div`:

```
<ion-content class="padding">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item >
      <div style="z-index: 1000;" ng-click="test()"> CLICK HERE</div>                                            
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.test = function(){
    alert('hello');
  };
})
```

See Playground: http://play.ionic.io/app/6227e101719b

Comment: For future searchers: my problem was the `$scope`, not the z-index.

Comment: does the same thing happens with the <ion-scroll> as well. I want to click on ion-scroll box and inner items as well?

Answer (score 6):

Adding **enable-pointer-events** class should do it.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="device in devices">
      <div class="enable-pointer-events" ng-click="deviceOption(device.id)"> CLICK HERE</div>                                            
  </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue

Using 'on-tap' instead of 'ng-click' solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method ever! Just change event to 'on-tap'

```
<ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="device in devices">
              <div on-tap="deviceOption(device.id)"> CLICK HERE</div>                                            
          </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```